# Understanding a representation of memory allocation, regarding the Perl pack function

Tags: perl, memory-management

I've boon looking up the Perl pack function and came across [this tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=224666).

All looked good, except when I got to the section about how the information was held in memory.

The tutorial does state that the first line is in decimal, second in hex, and the third as characters where applicable, and that pipe characters indicate field boundaries.

The data to be packed was derived from the following C structure:

```
struct SupplyRequest {
    time_t request_time;    // time request was entered
    int employee_id;        // employee making request
    char item[32];          // item requested
    short quantity;         // quantity needed
    short urgent;           // request is urgent
};
```

with the input data (quoted exactly from the tutorial):

"If monk number 217641 (hey! that's me!) placed an urgent order for two boxes of paperclips on January 1, 2003 at 1pm EST, $rec would contain the following (first line in decimal, second in hex, third as characters where applicable). Pipe characters indicate field boundaries."

When packed, the resultant data would resemble the following:

```
Offset   Contents (increasing addresses left to right)
     0   160  44  19  62| 41  82   3   0| 98 111 120 101 115  32 111 102
          A0  2C  13  3E| 29  52  03  00| 62  6f  78  65  73  20  6f  66
                                        |  b   o   x   e   s       o   f

    16    32 112  97 112 101 114  99 108 105 112 115   0   0   0   0   0
          20  70  61  70  65  72  63  6c  69  70  73  00  00  00  00  00
               p   a   p   e   r   c   l   i   p   s

    32     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0|  2   0|  1   0
          00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00| 02  00| 01  00
```

I'd like some help trying to understand what's going on here, what the above fields represent; i.e. what is meant by the offset etc.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It might be made clear if I read that entire tutorial, but I'm not going to do that, and I doubt anyone else will either. Please provide a clear question. Quote something out of the tutorial that doesn't make sense if you need to.

Comment: 'pack' is about data format conversion. It's not about memory allocation.

Comment: Skimming over the tutorial, the section on `pack` isn't about memory allocation (at least from a very strict sense; there's no mention of `malloc()` or `new` or anything similar).  It **is** about `pack`'s job:  converting data to different formats, often because you need to communicate with something other than Perl.  You may have more luck reading the official Perl pack documentation ( http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html , http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html )

Comment: OK, After reading some of the responses, I realizes that the columns are 3 representations of identical pieces of information (i.e. 62  6f  78  65  73  20  6f  66 is "boxes of" in hexidecimal, and the offset is the (thanks to ikegami) is "the offset (position) into the string at which the byte is located".
I think I was originally thrown by the "increasing addresses left to right" statement.
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string represents the representation of a instance of the following structure in memory.

```
struct SupplyRequest {
    time_t request_time;    // time request was entered
    int employee_id;        // employee making request
    char item[32];          // item requested
    short quantity;         // quantity needed
    short urgent;           // request is urgent
};
```

"Fields" refers to the fields of the structure (`request_time`, `employee_id`, ...).

"Offset" refers to the offset (position) into the string at which the byte is located.